# Error while connecting Raspberry Pi to GPIO7 pin

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, relay

I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi, which is connected in a relay box in GPIO7 pin. I have tested with `Gpio.board` and with `gpio.bcm` without success with this code:

```
#This program connects with gpio7
#setup pins
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)#mode Board
while True:
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    #GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)#mode Board
    time.sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    #GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW) #mode Board
    GPIO.cleanup()  #devuelve los pines a su estado inicial

exit()
```

This is the error both in one way and the other:

> Traceback (most recent call
> last):File"/home/pi/Desktop/RelayPrograms/5_7OnSleepOff.py", line 13,
> in GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)RuntimeError: Please set pin
> numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or
> GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can also try the [dedicated Stack Exchange site for Raspberri Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Lorena will also communicate my question in this community

Answer (score 3):

You set the pin numbering mode with `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` before the loop. The first loop will work as expected, but `GPIO.cleanup()` will undo your `setmode`, and you'll get the error on the second loop.

So, just put the cleanup at the end.

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)#mode Board
while True:
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    #GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)#mode Board
    time.sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(5) 
    #GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW) #mode Board

GPIO.cleanup()  #devuelve los pines a su estado inicial
exit()
```

Comment: This can seen clearly if a print statement is used inside the loop, it will successfully run once

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but it does not work, it does not skip any errors but it does not go off and on every 5 minutes as I want and it does not go to clear.

Comment: @Meirin.f You need a `sleep` after `GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)` as well, otherwise it will immediately go HIGH again in the next loop and you'll never see it... I just added it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution to my question:**

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import warnings
import time
from threading import Timer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False) ##Impido warning en ejecución

def blink4():#pin 7
        print ("Ejecucion iniciada...")
        time.sleep(5) ## Esperamos 1 segundo
        iteracion = 0
        while iteracion < 2: ## Segundos que durara la funcion
                GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT) ## Enciendo
                print ("Encendido")
                time.sleep(5) ## Esperamos 1 segundo
                GPIO.cleanup(4) ## Apago 
                print ("Apagado")
                time.sleep(5) ## Esperamos 1 segundo
                iteracion = iteracion + 2 ## Sumo 2 porque he hecho dos parpade$
        print ("Ejecucion finalizada")

def blink23(): #pin 16
        print ("Ejecucion iniciada...")
        time.sleep(5) ## Esperamos 1 segundo
        iteracion = 0
        while iteracion < 2: ## Segundos que durara la funcion
                GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT) ## Enciendo 
                print ("Encendido")
                time.sleep(5) ## Esperamos 1 segundo
                GPIO.cleanup(23) ## Apago 
                print ("Apagado")
                time.sleep(5) ## Esperamos 1 segundo
                iteracion = iteracion + 2 ## Sumo 2 porque he hecho dos parpade$
        print ("Ejecucion finalizada")

blink4()
blink23()
GPIO.cleanup() ## Hago una limpieza de los GPIO
```

> **It works right now, thank you all.**